# Convert hh:mm:ss format in seconds in SAS language?

Tags: sql, input, sas, dataset

What I'm asked to do at school is to convert a column of variable `ElapsedTime` in format `0:01:27.000` into a new column called `seconds`. So `0:01:27.000` => `87`
In my task, they are suggesting to use the function `input` I couldn't find anything to make it work.

Comment: It depends on if it's a character or numeric value. If it's a character variable you need to use INPUT() as show via data _null_, however, if it's a numeric variable you need to remove the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ElapsedTime` is character variable, then you should use `input` function with `time16.` format:

```
data have;/*init sample data*/
   ElapsedTime = '0:01:27.000';
run;

data want;/*create new dataset with new variable "seconds"*/
   set have;/*your dataset name instead of "have"*/
   seconds = input(ElapsedTime,time16.);
   put _all_;
run;
```

> ElapsedTime=0:01:27.000 seconds=87 *ERROR*=0 *N*=1

But if `ElapsedTime` is numeric variable that formatted in `time16.` then you should change format to `best.`:

```
data want;/*init sample data*/
  format ElapsedTime time16.;
  ElapsedTime = '0:01:27.000't;
run;

data want;/*create new dataset with new variable "seconds"*/
   set have;/*your dataset name instead of "have"*/
   seconds = input(ElapsedTime,best.);
   put _all_;
run;
```

> ElapsedTime=0:01:27 seconds=87 *ERROR*=0 *N*=1

Answer (score 3):

TIME in-format

```
35         data _null_;
36            x = '0:01:27.000';
37            y = input(x,time16.);
38            put _all_;
39            run;

x=0:01:27.000 y=87 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
```

Comment: This works for one data but not for all the datas of the variables ??

Comment: ?? @gregouz1995 if you give more details you get better help.

Comment: This is example code. You need to replace the X with your variable and point it towards your data set within the data step.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this then:

```
data want; *output data;
set have; *input data;

time_sas = input(oldVar, time16.); *does the conversion;

run;
```